# New to Selenium - cannot access RemoteWebDriver error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Selenium and I have tried to setup my first Selenium test using IntelliJ and Selenium 2. I have followed the tutorials on the official Selenium site but I get this error:

```
cannot access org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
    class file for org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver not found
```

This is the tutorial I am using - http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#chapter03-reference

This is the location for the Maven setup I followed - http://seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_installing_java_driver_Sel20_via_maven.html#importing-maven-into-intellij-reference

Here is the code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class MyAppHomePageTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    } 
}
```

The error occurs when I try to create a FirefoxDriver instance. Do I need to have the Selenium server as I thought this is no longer required.

I have tried the same in Eclipse and received the same error.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You should use this Maven dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

According to this picture, you don't need a selenium-server  dependency:

[image]

source : http://seleniumhq.org/download/maven.html

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've setup the project in eclipse with selenium-java.jar and selenium-server-standalone.jar dependencies and it works. Seems like the latter jar is required.

Comment: I still can't get the project working in IntelliJ even though I have added the above 2 jar files as reference libraries.

Comment: You should not add selenium-java.jar by hand : you have to let Maven get the transitive dependencies (all drivers which are listed in picture and here : http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/2.1.0/selenium-java-2.1.0.pom)