# The type org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver cannot be resolved

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium3

I am relatively new to selenium , Wanted to try Selenium 3.0 with Firefox browser using Maven project
Here is my code

```
package com.sample.maven_sample;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class GoogleHomePageTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String driverPath = "C:\\selenium-drivers\\geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe";
        System.out.println("launching firefox browser");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverPath);
        WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        if(driver!=null) {
            driver.close();
        }
    }
```

Here are the dependencies in my pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am getting following error in my project

> The type org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver cannot be
>   resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I am not able to understand what is dependency that I am missing in my pom.xml
googled with many keywords for possible solution but nothing worked 
Found similar question here [New to Selenium - cannot access RemoteWebDriver error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800924/new-to-selenium-cannot-access-remotewebdriver-error)
The post is quite old and its good for Selenium 2.0

**Note:** When I manually download selenium-server-standalone-3.1.0.jar from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ and Add it as External Jar the issue gets resolved. But i am looking for some dependency to be added in my pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

'RemoteWebDriver' dependency not added to your project.You need to add maven dependency of 'RemoteWebDriver' to fix this issue.

Add below dependency in your pom.xml and refresh project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

To my surprise I just needed to include one dependency in pom.xml

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am really not sure what did i configure wrong in first place 
Here are the steps which I followed which resolved my issue

1. Delete all the Selenium related dependencies from Users\Username.m2\repository folder
2. Add above dependency to pom
3. Update maven project  ( Above error gone with this step)
4. mvn clean
5. mvn compile
6. Run as Java Application ( I was able to see Firefox getting launched)

Comment: Generally, you can avoid deleting anything out of .m2/repository by adding the -U (force update of dependencies) flag to mvn.